# React component with function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs, jsx

I have a react class with some div and I want to add some extra HTML from a function.

When I run this I get an error saying that OverlayButton is not defined. My inspiration is from [HERE](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

I know that I can split the OverlayButton out in a separate class, but it is just a dumb button with no logic.

```
export default class Widget extends React.Component {

  OverlayButton(props) {
     return (
      <div
        className={props.className}
        onClick={props.handler}
        ref='select'>
          <i className="material-icons">
            {props.icon}
          </i>
      </div>
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="photo-widget-content"></div>
          <div className="photo-widget-header"></div>
            <img src={this.props.photo.url}></img>
            return <OverlayButton icon="check" handler="" className=""/>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're almost there, just replace** `<OverlayButton ... />` **with** `<this.OverlayButton ... />`

---

Strictly speaking, in response to the other answer (which is also correct), there is no need to call it as a function, since you could rely on JSX to do it for you.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/5k2w00sp/3/) an example.

```
class Widget extends React.Component {

  OverlayButton(props) {
     return (
       <div>
         Button
       </div>
     );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <this.OverlayButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Widget />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

---

**With that being said**, I'd probably wouldn't define `OverlayButton` as an instance method of a class, but rather move it on top of the class and simply define it as a function... something like this:

```
const OverlayButton = (props)=> {
  return (
    <div>
      Button
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then

```
class Widget extends React.Component { 
   ...

   render() {
     return <OverlayButton ... />
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use OverlayButton as a function (method) you need to call it inside `{}` braces:

```
export default class Widget extends React.Component {

  OverlayButton(props) {
     return (
      <div
        className={props.className}
        onClick={props.handler}
        ref='select'>
          <i className="material-icons">
            {props.icon}
          </i>
      </div>
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="photo-widget-content"></div>
          <div className="photo-widget-header"></div>
          <img src={this.props.photo.url} />
          {this.OverlayButton({
            icon: 'check',
            handler: function() {},
            className: ''
          })}
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup that did it - it's not quite how discribed at fb docs - who cares. Thanks

Comment: @TareqAl-Zubaidi Yes, but in case of component usage I would move `OverlayButton` as separate component/function, not  same `Widget` method.

Comment: you don't have to, but it's a better design

Comment: @leo of course it is but it is good to know the possibilities

Comment: exactly... he only suggested a possibility without contradicting with your suggestion:-)